# Problema con CSS - Background Color

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente código:

```css
.llamativo{
 border-left: 1px double darkgray;
 border-bottom: 1px double darkgray;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px inset;
 border-radius: 4px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 22px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 5px 0;
}
.llamativo .pred{
 background-color: #eee!important;
}
.llamativo .rojo{
 background-color: #ce0005!important;
}
.llamativo .azul{
 background-color: #0082bf!important;
}
.llamativo .piel{
 background-color: #eecc86!important;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="llamativo azul">Título</h1>
```

Las clases **.rojo .azul .pred .piel** no se aplican, no entiendo porqué.
Las estoy llamando, como es el ejemplo del **Snippet**, pero no funciona.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se llaman porque la segunda clase no se encuentra en un elemento posterior deberías quitar el espacio después de `.llamativo` dejándolo de esta manera `.llamativo.color`

```css
.llamativo{
 border-left: 1px double darkgray;
 border-bottom: 1px double darkgray;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px inset;
 border-radius: 4px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 22px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 5px 0;
}
.llamativo.pred{
 background-color: #eee!important;
}
.llamativo.rojo{
 background-color: #ce0005!important;
}
.llamativo.azul{
 background-color: #0082bf!important;
}
.llamativo.piel{
 background-color: #eecc86!important;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="llamativo azul">Título</h1>
```

Comment: Rayos... :( Se me pasó ... Las prisas. Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Eso es por que por ejemplo la clase `.pred` dentro del CSS debe encontrarse dentro de otra llamada `.llamativo` para que te funcione deberias eliminar los espacios que tienes entre los selectores por ejemplo `.llamativo.pred`

Answer (score 1):

Lo unico que tienes que hacer es a `.llamativo .pred` quitarle `.llamativo` y dejarle solo la clase. o pegar las clases en caso de querer el estilo solo cuando las 2 estén en el elemento

En **css** para hacer referencia a un hijo de un elemento hacemos esto:

```
.llamativo .pred {...}
```

y para agregar un estilo solo si el elemento tiene dos clases hay que quitar el espacio entre ellas algo así

```css
.llamativo{
 border-left: 1px double darkgray;
 border-bottom: 1px double darkgray;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px inset;
 border-radius: 4px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 22px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 5px 0;
}
.llamativo.pred{
 background-color: #eee!important;
}
.llamativo.rojo{
 background-color: #ce0005!important;
}
.llamativo.azul{
 background-color: #0082bf!important;
}
.llamativo.piel{
 background-color: #eecc86!important;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="llamativo azul">Título</h1><!--tiene que tener las 2 clases para agregar los estilos-->
<h1 class="azul">Título</h1><!--No tiene las 2 clases y por eso no agrega los estilos-->
```

y si simplemente es una clase independiente es así:

```css
.llamativo{
 border-left: 1px double darkgray;
 border-bottom: 1px double darkgray;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px inset;
 border-radius: 4px;
 font-weight: bold;
 font-size: 22px;
 padding: 10px;
 margin: 5px 0;
}
.pred{
 background-color: #eee!important;
}
.rojo{
 background-color: #ce0005!important;
}
.azul{
 background-color: #0082bf!important;
}
.piel{
 background-color: #eecc86!important;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="llamativo azul">Título</h1>
```